# Using "this" in nested, modular methods and preserving namespaces

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I have a giant JavaScript monolith and used a module based approach to make it more structured.

However, I'm a bit lost on how to use the "this" keyword for nested functions, without overwriting each other, like the example below might demonstrate

```js
function Fruit() {
  const self = this;

  this.fruits = [];

  this.addFruit = function (fruit) {
    self.fruits.push(fruit);
  };

  // Buy locally
  this.localStore = (function () {
    const self_localStore = this;
    this.buyArray = [];

    this.buy = function (fruit) {
      console.log("Bought locally");
      self_localStore.buyArray = this;
    };

    return this;
  })();

  // Buy from online store
  this.onlineStore = (function () {
    const self_onlineStore = this;
    this.buyArray = [];

    this.buy = function (fruit) {
      console.log("Bought online");
      self_onlineStore.buyArray = this;
    };

    return this;
  })();

  return this;
}

let fruit = new Fruit();

fruit.localStore.buy("apple"); // -> Bought online, instead of Bought locally
```

The `localStore.buy()` method is for obvious reasons overwritten by the `onlineStore.buy()` method, as they both are returned to the Fruit() methods scope, use the same name and the last one overwrites the first one.

So, what would be the solution to allow "namespaces" like onlineStore and localStore without using an object that has these nested methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), `this` equals `window` or `undefined` (depending on whether you use strict mode or not):

```js
(function() { console.log(this === window); })() // True
```

The `this` keyword is being assigned the object from which the function is called, for example:

```js
const obj = {
  fun: function() { console.log(this === obj); } 
}

obj.fun(); // True
```

If you want to create some namespace which has its own state, I suggest you to do it with a simple object like this:

```js
function Fruit() {
  const self = this;

  this.fruits = [];

  this.addFruit = function (fruit) {
    self.fruits.push(fruit);
  };

  // Buy locally
  this.localStore = {
    buyArray: [],

    buy: function (fruit) {
      this.buyArray.push(fruit);
      console.log("Bought locally:", this.buyArray.join(', '));
    }

  };

  // Buy from online store
  this.onlineStore =  {
    buyArray: [],

    buy: function (fruit) {
      this.buyArray.push(fruit);
      console.log("Bought online:", this.buyArray.join(', '));
    }

  };

  return this;
}

let fruit = new Fruit();

fruit.localStore.buy("apple"); // -> Bought online, instead of Bought locally
fruit.localStore.buy("banana");
fruit.onlineStore.buy("orange");
```

However, you may not like the literal objects, because they don't provide real encapsulation (the `buyArray` property can be accessed from outside of the `buy` function).

So you could also encapsulate the state in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) like you initially tried to do:

```js
function Fruit() {
  const self = this;

  this.fruits = [];

  this.addFruit = function (fruit) {
    self.fruits.push(fruit);
  };

  // Buy locally
  this.localStore = (function() {
    const buyArray = [];

    const buy = function (fruit) {
      buyArray.push(fruit);
      console.log("Bought locally:", buyArray.join(', '));
    };
    
    return { buy };

  })();

  // Buy from online store
  this.onlineStore = (function() {
    const buyArray = [];

    const buy = function (fruit) {
      buyArray.push(fruit);
      console.log("Bought online:", buyArray.join(', '));
    };
    
    return { buy };

  })();

  return this;
}

let fruit = new Fruit();

fruit.localStore.buy("apple"); // -> Bought online, instead of Bought locally
fruit.localStore.buy("banana");
fruit.onlineStore.buy("orange");
```

Comment: I already knew about your first two statements with the code snippets, but I still appreciate them, thanks!
Moreover, I also knew about object literals beeing a solution, but it doesn't feel right to have them, beside all other kinds of module based methods. So, is there a way to do it with `localStore` and `onlineStore` beeing methods?

Comment: I dont get why you want them to be methods while you use them with `fruit.localStore.buy("apple");` which clearly shows that `localStore` should be an object. What "doesnt't feel right" about it? What bothers you is that there is no real encapsulation and the objects and their `buyArray` properties can be accessed from outside?

Comment: I guess I'm just used to following the module pattern with declaring methods and each method represents an "area" of the code, while at the same time using dot notation to access either the first level method, or sublevel methods with an "area" prepended. I'm working both backend and frontend and am somehow obsessed to have similar structures.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide what I think you want.

Comment: I see, I guess I'm not getting around returning an object. An seems like I have to use `return { ...this }` to include all methods.
Well, I accepted your answer for now, eventough i hoped for something else :p

Answer (score 1):

you are creating a function variable in both function. but this.onlinestore override the function variable of fruit. this is not different from setter function. think about a you can set a variable from two different method. and from top to buttom, in online store function you override the this.buy method.

you can use bottom example.

```js
function Fruit() {
  const self = this;

  this.fruits = [];

  this.addFruit = function (fruit) {
    self.fruits.push(fruit);
  };

  // Buy locally
  this.localStore = () =>{
  console.log('local store');
    const self_localStore = this;
    this.buyArray = [];

    this.buy = function (fruit) {
      console.log("Bought locally");
      self_localStore.buyArray = this;
    };

    return this;
  };

  // Buy from online store
  this.onlineStore = () => {
    console.log('online store')
    const self_onlineStore = this;
    this.buyArray = [];

    this.buy = function (fruit) {
      console.log("Bought online");
      self_onlineStore.buyArray = this;
    };

    return this;
  };

  return this;
}

let fruit = new Fruit();

fruit.localStore().buy("apple"); // -> Bought online, instead of Bought locally
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but the difference of your solution is that instead of invoking both `localStore` and `onlineStore` directly, you do it when calling the method, which may feel unatural to do `fruit.localStore().buy("apple");` instead of `fruit.localStore.buy("apple");`